# Azure DevOps, Organization Settings - Will enabling "SSH authentication" invalidate existing OAuth tokens?

Tags: ssh, azure-devops

If I enable `SSH authentication` for an Azure DevOps organization, will that enforce (only allow) SSH key pairs to be used for Git authentication requests, explicitly? Or will existent OAuth tokens still work as-intended after enabling SSH keys? In my scenario, currently, `SSH authentication` is disabled and `Third-party application access via OAuth` is enabled going into this question. Thanks for your time. ( Options found under:  Azure DevOps > Organization Settings (bottom left) > Policies (left middle) )

I am assuming enabling both allows for either to be used, but want to confirm before potentially blocking developers from being able to push code.

I would like all developer workstations to use SSH key authentication instead of OAuth, and don't want to put a wrench in their system in the meantime. Also I much prefer using private key authentication simply because of the inherent security benefits of using asymmetric cryptography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your organization allows access for **all** authentication methods(OAuth, SSH authentication, PATs). You can limit access, but you must specifically restrict access for each method. When you deny access to an authentication method, no application can access your organization. Any app that previously had access gets an authentication error and has no access to your organization.

So enabling SSH authentication will not affect OAuth authentication.

Here is the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-application-access-policies?view=azure-devops) you can refer to.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to enable. We have it enabled in our organization, and almost none of us actually have added SSH keys. We're pretty much exclusively OAuth.